# Codelens not showing reference on inner functions

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I configured Codelens on VSCODE, and yet, it only shows number of references of `Objects`!
I have the following Object definition, and I want to show the number of references **on top of the inner functions too.**

```
export const VAR = {
    PROP1: {
        innerFunction: (id: number) => .....
    },
    PROP2: {
        innerFunction: (id: number) => .....
    },
}
```

I configured Codelens, and I'm expecting to see references of inner props too